# Configure Intellij for Java 8 lambda defaults

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to have intellij always declare lambdas in a certain way.

For instance, sometime intellij will refactor a lambda into:

```
method(length, index -> { return null; })
```

using blocks but no parentheses on the parameter index. It makes it hard to adjust at time.

I would like it to always use this syntax instead:

```
method(length, (index) -> { return null; })

method(length, (Integer index) -> { return null; })
```

And always use blocks, unless it is a method reference, ie obj::method.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in IntelliJ 13 (but maybe in 14?). Your workaround, of course, is the refactoring options (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) "Expand Lambda expression body to {...}".

What you want is a bit like saying, "I want all of my anonymous classes to be private static inner classes because it's easier to refactor." While true, you don't *need* all the extra syntax; and when you do, the IDE refactoring tools are there to help you.

Comment: Yes, something to say that "Always Expand Lambda expression body to {} " ... As you suggest there is the refactoring option, but that is two steps away. First yoy create your inner class, new Runnable() {} .. and then you refactor to a lambda, then you have to expand. I find that the new Runnable() {} and then make into a lambda is too far, but it is easier to get intellij to generate the lambda that way. You get no help if you don't start typing new, at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: @SecretService Unfortunately, code completion and formatting options for lambdas are woefully inadequate in IntelliJ 13, hopefully they will be enhanced in future versions...

Comment: I will post a youtrack for this.